# Adding analysis privileges to ArcGIS Online application?

Tags: arcgis-online

I'd like to use ArcGIS Online analysis services in my web app application.

When I try accessing the service: http://analysis.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/tasks/GPServer?f=pjson&token=

I get this error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "code" : 401,
    "message" : "You do not have permissions to use this resource.",
    "details" : [ ]
  }
}
```

When I check the privileges of my ArcGIS Online app using: https://.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/portals/self?f=pjson&token=

I don't see analysis privilege in appInfo section:

```
"appInfo": {
    "appId": "-------",
    "itemId": "----------",
    "appOwner": "----",
    "orgId": "------",
    "appTitle": "myApp",
    "privileges": [
      "premium:user:demographics",
      "premium:user:elevation",
      "premium:user:geocode",
      "premium:user:geoenrichment",
      "premium:user:networkanalysis"
    ]
  }
```

How can I add analysis privileges to my app?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not the account administrator, maybe your user role has been restricted to perform certain functions.

http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/administer/configure-roles.htm

Comment: My account is administrator. I'll contact the ESRI Support team to try to find a solution.
Thanks :)

Comment: @yo_haha Did you ever find a solution to this? If so, it would be good to post as an answer;)

Comment: @Aaron I have no idea if I found a solution or not :( I moved on to other projects...